# How do I reinstall cups in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: printing

I accidentally deleted some Cups files in Ubuntu 18.04, and now. obviously, it does not work.
How can I reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove it and install it without problem on 18.04 using the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove cups
sudo apt install cups
```

Comment: This seems to be working in 20.04 too, but still didn't solve my CUPS problem (Unable to get printer status)